# Greenplum Error: Interconnect error writing an outgoing packet: Operation not permitted

Tags: postgresql, greenplum

ETL jobs are fialed with Greenplum Error

Interconnect error writing an outgoing packet: Operation not permitted (seg20 slice1 NVMBD2AMK050D00:40002 pid=863)

Did any one face this error before

I checked the logs but didnt get anything specific,

also tried below solution given @Pivotal's site

https://support.pivotal.io/hc/en-us/articles/202967503-Pivotal-Greenplum-GPDB-query-failed-with-Interconnect-error-writing-an-outgoing-packet-Operation-not-permitted-

Please help

Comment: Can you provide more details?  Where is this installed?  Do you have iptables enabled?  How many sessions are there?  What were you doing when this error happened?  You mentioned "ETL jobs".  Are you loading data from a remote host?  If so, can the segment hosts connect to the ETL host?

Comment: Thanks for replying Jon IPTABLES are already flushed and disabled as suggested in 1st solution in given link, 2nd solution is not working as that parameter is unknown to system, I have centos6.4 @all servers, Jobs are loading data from external sources and yes segment host are able to connect to ETL host and vice versa